# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 11

Tags: java, database

Thank you Alexandre but now I keep receiving the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

But I have 11 question marks and 11 parameters so I don't understand this error either.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO STAFFDIR VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, LN);
stmt.setString(2, FN);
stmt.setString(3, M);
stmt.setString(4, Phone);
stmt.setInt(5, DC);
stmt.setString(6, Email);
stmt.setInt(7, FC);
stmt.setString(8, Title);
stmt.setInt(9, LC);
stmt.setString(10, Picture);
stmt.setString(11, PC);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

------------------ Original message----------------------

The code below generates the following error. Why? This is an MS Access 2010 .accdb database. The table in question does have another field called ID
which is defined as a primary key. But I didn't think that I would need to reference it in any way though. Do I? Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

```
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O First Name = John
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Last Name = Doe
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Middle = M
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Phone = 212 999-9999
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O DeptCode = 0
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Email = nbroat@msn.com
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Title = None
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O FaxCode = 2
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O LocCode = 1
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Picture = none
[5/8/14 10:06:34:986 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Pic_Code = N
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemOut     O Error occurred     java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 11.
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 11.
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6969)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7126)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3161)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:228)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:103)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at cophonebk.COaddstaff.performTask(COaddstaff.java:104)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at cophonebk.COaddstaff.doPost(COaddstaff.java:39)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3944)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at  com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)  
[5/8/14 10:06:35:047 EDT] 00000025 SystemErr     R  at    com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)  


        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        String LN = (String)request.getParameter("Last_Name");          
    String FN = (String)request.getParameter("First_Name");
    String M  = (String)request.getParameter("Middle");
    String Ph = (String)request.getParameter("Phone");

        String Dept_Code = (String)request.getParameter("Dept_Code");
        Integer DC = Integer.valueOf(Dept_Code);

    String E = (String)request.getParameter("Email");
    String Fax_Code = (String)request.getParameter("Fax_Code"); 
    Integer FC = Integer.valueOf(Fax_Code);

    String T = (String)request.getParameter("Title");

    String Loc_Code = (String)request.getParameter("Loc_Code");
    Integer LC = Integer.valueOf(Loc_Code);

    String Pic = (String)request.getParameter("Picture");
    String PC = (String)request.getParameter("Pic_Code");

    System.out.println("First Name = " + FN);
    System.out.println("Last Name = " + LN);
    System.out.println("Middle = " + M);
    System.out.println("Phone = " + Ph);
        System.out.println("DeptCode = " + DC);
        System.out.println("Email = " + E);
        System.out.println("Title = " + T);
        System.out.println("FaxCode = " + FC);
        System.out.println("LocCode = " + LC);
        System.out.println("Picture = " + Pic);
        System.out.println("Pic_Code = " + PC);

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:CentralOfficePhoneDirectory");

        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO STAFFDIR(Last_Name,First_Name,Middle,Phone,Dept_Code,Email,Title,Fax_Code,Loc_Code,Picture,Pic_Code) VALUES(LN,FN,M,Ph,DC,E,T,FC,LC,Pic,PC)");
            result = stmt.executeQuery();

            try {
                stmt.close();
            }  catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
                conn.close();
        }   catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }           
            return;
        } // End of try

        catch (SQLException e) {
              System.out.println("Error occurred " + e);
              e.printStackTrace();
              return;
        }
```

Comment: Only relevant error parts *please*

Comment: There are no parameters in that prepared statement, so I don't see how that code produces the posted error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
           PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO STAFFDIR(Last_Name,First_Name,Middle,Phone,Dept_Code,Email,Title,Fax_Code,Loc_Code,Picture,Pic_Code) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           stmt.setString(1, LN);
           stmt.setString(2, FN);
           stmt.setString(3, M);
           stmt.setString(4, Phone);
           stmt.setInt(5, DC);
           stmt.setString(6, Email);
           stmt.setInt(7, FC);
           stmt.setString(8, Title);
           stmt.setInt(9, LC);
           stmt.setString(10, Picture);
           stmt.setString(11, PC);
           stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: There is an option to edit your answer, so please use it instead of posting two answers (in reference to your *other* answer below).

Comment: The poster changed the original post, adding a different error

Comment: Forgive my poor use of this system Mike. Anyways, thank you again, Alexander but now I get java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. But 5,7,and 9 are defined as integer in the table. Are we sure I don't need to make any reference to the Primary Key? That would be the 12th field in the DB. Is that considered item 0? Or should I number stmt's 2 thr 12? Thanks again. And sorry again Mike.

Comment: I understand that. However the OP updated his original post. Therefore it seems that your first answer is now irrelevant.  Additionally the OP should remove the original message if that part of the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Wait! Stop the presses. 5 8 & 9 are numeric in the db. Back in a sec with the results.

Comment: That did it! Thank you sir!  I will now try to close this question with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the values to the parameters. The error is because you are not providing any parameters.

Take a look in here for examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/05_dev4.htm

Comment: Thank you Alexandre but now I continue to receive java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. I will append the new example to my example above.